# How to remove Header in csv file generated by sql command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on sql script for getting data from database to csv file,for that i created batch file.when i run batch file it genarated below table as a result
but with result is showing with some dummy data like "Changed database context to 'KMSSource'." and "(1 rows affected)". I want only table and not "Changed database context to 'KMSSource'." and "(1 rows affected)".

I'm using this code 
Note:This is sql server query.

create TABLE TempTable
(
   IBS_Total int,
   IBS_Active int,
   IBS_InActive int,
   IBS_Only int,
   KMS_Active int,
  KMS_InActive int
)
INSERT INTO TempTable (IBS_Total,IBS_Active,IBS_InActive,IBS_Only,KMS_Active,KMS_InActive) 
select (@IBS_Active+@IBS_INActive),@IBS_Active,@IBS_INActive,@KMS_DEVICENR,@KMS_Active,@KMS_OnlyTotal;
drop table #KMS_DEU

```
USE [KMSSource] 
select * from TempTable
go
```

and I'm getting this result

```
**Changed database context to 'KMSSource'.**
IBS_Total   IBS_Active  IBS_InActive IBS_Only    KMS_Active  KMS_InActive
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------------
      41621        8632        32989          74       11916         3358

**(1 rows affected)**
```

**BatchfileCode is :-->**

```
@echo off   
echo script executing....
:begin
sqlcmd -S%server%  -b -i"Data\Report_IBS_KMS_KU_DUE.sql" -o"Extract\Report_IBS_KMS_KU_DUE.csv"
:end
Exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: @Suhas Dakhare :- You written in question, that you create batch file

Comment: Report_IBS_KMS_KU_DUE.sql file has only one posted query here or more code?

Comment: Yes I craeted batch file but source file for this is sql file.I just executing Sql file by using Batch file.

Comment: I assume you are using the SQLCMD utility.  Remove the USE statement and instead specify d parameter for the database context.  Consider using BCP instead of SQLCMD to export data.

Comment: dan:If I remove the USE then it giving error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error when removing the USE statement, then you need to qualify the table names in the query, as below.  Also be setting NO COUNT ON, you will get the message about rows affected.

---

SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE KMSSource.dbo.TempTable
( IBS_Total INT, IBS_Active INT, IBS_InActive INT, IBS_Only INT, KMS_Active INT, KMS_InActive INT )
INSERT  INTO KMSSource.dbo.#KMS_DEU
( IBS_Total, IBS_Active, IBS_InActive, IBS_Only, KMS_Active, KMS_InActive )
SELECT  ( @IBS_Active + @IBS_INActive ), @IBS_Active, @IBS_INActive, @KMS_DEVICENR, @KMS_Active, @KMS_OnlyTotal;
DROP TABLE KMSSource.dbo.#KMS_DEU

Comment: sorry receiving errors when trying to format the code as code.

Comment: Hi Dbloch @ My main aim behind this is to remove "Changed database context to 'KMSSource'." from my csv file.

Comment: What error are you getting when you remove the USE KMSSource statement?

Comment: If what I suggested worked, please mark it as the answer